# AngularJS ui-select allow-clear does not trigger ngChange vent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

Developing with AngularJS 1.6.9 and using ui-select component 0.19.8. The ngChange event is not fired when the button to clear the component ("allow-clear") is clicked. Is there another event or technique that can be used to handle when the clear button is clicked?

The "allow-clear" directive does not trigger the "ng-change" event when clicked. We need to handle this action.